# url redirections not working for anonymous users

Tags: 8, caching

I have set a redirect rule in EventSubscriber. So according to rule, when I hit example.com/my-page in browser, it should redirect to example.com/success or some external url also.

But issue is(for anonymous user):

On hitting first time this url "example.com/my-page", REDIRECT SUCCESS!! But on second time it does not redirect. It remains "example.com/my-page" only.

Now If I logged in, flush all cache, then again log out and check "example.com/my-page", it again works -- REDIRECT SUCCESS!! But again after redirecting first time when accessed the same, it stops redirecting.

Comment: try implementing cache dependecy interface also  class and include these methods RedirectSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface ,CacheableDependencyInterface  {
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }
  public function getCacheContexts() {
    return [];
  }
  public function getCacheTags() {
    return [];
      }

Comment: @Shreya, I have used `use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata;` and put my request uri in context `$this->context->fromRequest($request);` and also I have tried `$response->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray([])->addCacheTags(['rendered']));` Can you help me more figuring out the root cause of this issue?

Comment: did u try wht i said ?? it is not working ??

Comment: No Shreya, I tried exactly same what you have written, but it is redirecting only for authenticated users not anonymous users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because of the page cache for anonymous users. The cache is implemented as middleware and runs before any event subscriber, even if you set a  high priority.

If your site serves dynamically generated responses and redirects for every single request, then you don't need this cache and you can uninstall the module **Internal Page Cache**.

If you want to disable the page cache in code:

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

This will deny any page caching on the current request.

Comment: Is there any other alternative If I don't wanna install Internal Page cache? Can I achieve this pro-grammatically rather than manually disable module for Internal page cache?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, see the edited answer.

Comment: Should I use it when saving form to database or at event subscriber where redirecting rule is written?

Comment: The kill switch can be triggered anywhere in code of the same request. However if you set a redirect in a form to /example.com/my-page, then you get a second request, and a kill switch triggered in the form will no longer be active.